# Kähler form on a Hermitian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, hermitian-matrices

Let $(M, h)$ be a Hermitian manifold. We then have a Riemannian metric $g=\Re(h)$ and a real-valued differential $2$-form $\omega = - \Im(h)$.

I want to see why locally we can write $$\omega = \frac{i}{2} \sum_{j,k} h_{jk} dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k$$ but I'm not sure how this expression is derived. If I have understood correctly $\omega$ is of type $(1,1)$? Starting from $\omega = - \Im(h)$ if we consider vectors $u, v$ where $u$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and $v$ $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear then can we expand $$\omega(u,v) = -\Im(h(u,v))$$ to get to this local expression?

Comment: What do you mean when you write "$u,v$ where $u$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear and $v$ $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear"? This makes it sound like you should go review the definitions, and perhaps that would help solving your problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex $k$ form $\omega$ on $M$ is said to be a $(p,q)$-form if $p + q = k$ and each $\omega_x : \Lambda^kT_xM \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (which is $\mathbb{R}$-multilinear) verifies for all $(u_1,\ldots,u_k) \in (T_xM)^k$ and all $z \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$
\omega_x(zu_1,\ldots,zu_k) = z^q\overline{z}^p\omega_x(u_1,\ldots,u_k).
$$
In particular, $\omega$ is a $(k,0)$ form, each $\omega_x$ is $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear and in your case,
$$
\omega_x(zu,zv) = -\Im(h_x(zu,zv)) = -\Im(z\overline{z}h_x(u,v)) = -z\overline{z}\Im(h_x(u,v)) = z\overline{z}\omega_x(u,v).
$$
It works because $z\overline{z} = |z|^2$ is real. Now, in a local holomorphic coordinates system $z_1,\ldots,z_n$, set $h_{j\overline{k}} = h\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}\right)$. It is a smooth function from an open subset of $M$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and for all vector fields $X = \sum_{j = 1}^n X_j\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$ and $Y = \sum_{j = 1}^n Y_j\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$, we have,
\begin{align*}
h(X,Y) & = h\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n X_j\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},\sum_{k = 1}^n Y_k\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}\right)\\
& = \sum_{j = 1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n X_j\overline{Y_k}h\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}\right)\\
& = \sum_{j = 1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n h_{j,\overline{k}}X_j\overline{Y_k}\\
& = \sum_{j = 1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n h_{j,\overline{k}}(dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k})(X,Y).
\end{align*}
Hence, $h = \sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z}_k$.

Now, the conjugate symmetry of $h$ implies that for all $j,k$, $h_{k\overline{j}} = \overline{h_{j\overline{k}}}$. In other words, the matrices $(h_{j\overline{k}}(x))$ are Hermitian (and definite positive because $h$ is) so for all $j,k$,
\begin{align*}
\Im(h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k}) & = -\frac{i}{2}\left(h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - \overline{h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k}}\right)\\
& = -\frac{i}{2}\left(h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - h_{k\overline{j}}d\overline{z_j} \otimes dz_k\right).
\end{align*}
We deduce that,
\begin{align*}
\omega & = \sum_{j,k = 1}^n \frac{i}{2}\left(h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - h_{k\overline{j}}d\overline{z_j} \otimes dz_k\right)\\
& = \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{k\overline{j}}d\overline{z_j} \otimes dz_k\\
& = \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}d\overline{z_k} \otimes dz_j\\
& = \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}(dz_j \otimes d\overline{z_k} - d\overline{z_k} \otimes dz_j)\\
& = \frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k = 1}^n h_{j\overline{k}}dz_j \wedge d\overline{z_k}.
\end{align*}